# Getting statistic arguments to work in modified headers of a gtsummary table

Tags: r, r-markdown, gtsummary

I`m running this code:

```
twbysexo_a <-
  estrato_a %>%#Al diseño muestral se le aplica lo siguiente
  tbl_strata(##Genera la tabla por estrato
    strata = teletrab_3,#Variable en columna, por la que se estratifica
    
    .tbl_fun = ###unción anidada, lo que hará en cada estrato
      ~ .x %>%
      tbl_svysummary(include = PB1, ####Variables en las filas 
                     percent = "column",#### Porcentaje columna, fila o total
                     missing = "no", ####No tomar en cuenta perdidos
                     digits = ~2)%>% ####Redondear a dos dígitos
      modify_header(label = "**Sexo**")%>% ###Título del encabezado de la columna de variables
      modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA, abbreviation = F)%>% ###No añadir notas al pie
      remove_row_type(PB1, type = "header"),###Quitar el encabezado de la variable en las filas (se pone por defecto)
    .header = "**{strata}**"###Añadir las etiquetas de la variable que se estratifica (no sale en r-markdown)
  )%>%#Al objeto creado con todo lo de arriba
  modify_column_hide(c("var_type_3", "stat_0_3"
                       )) #Oculta la columnna NA de todo el objeto
  twbysexo_a
```

And my output is this:

[image]

I would like to edit the headers where the sub-strata N are, so I first I check the names of the columns I want to modify:

```
twbysexo_a %>% show_header_names()
```

With this result:

```
Column Name   Column Header      
------------  -------------------
label         **Sexo**           
stat_0_1      **N = 32,617,831** 
stat_0_2      **N = 4,681,838**
```

So I want to modify both `stat_0_1`, `stat_0_2` columns adding a pipe to the object `twbysexo_a`:

```
twbysexo_a%>% modify_header(stat_0_1 = "**No teletrabaja, N= 32,617,831 **", stat_0_2 = "**Teletrabaja, N= 4,681,838 **"
```

And I got my intended ouput, having both columns named afther the labels they represent in the strata and with their respectives N's.

[image]

I need to do this since the spanning header (where the stratas labels are located) doesn't show when I ask for the r-markdown syntax of the object. But, as you can see, I'm doing the modification in a very "manually" way, when I tried to use the statistic arguments `{n} , {N}, {N_obs}, {N_nonmiss}` or the `{level}` argument to call the label names or the N`s into the modified headers I always got errors. Here are some examples:

````
>twbysexo_b<-twbysexo_a %>% modify_header(stat_0_1 = "**No teletrabaja, N = {N}**", stat_0_2 = "**Teletrabaja, N = {N}**")```

Error: glue cannot interpolate functions into strings.
* object 'N' is a function.

>twbysexo_b<-twbysexo_a %>% modify_header(stat_0_1 = "**No teletrabaja, N = {n}**", stat_0_2 = "**Teletrabaja, N = {n}**")```

Error: glue cannot interpolate functions into strings.
* object 'n' is a function.  

>twbysexo_b<-twbysexo_a %>% modify_header(stat_0_1 = "**{level}, N = {N}**", stat_0_2 = "**{level}, N = {N}**")

Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'level' not found
````

So since I need to apply this exact same code to multiple variables and stratas, is there a way to make the statistic or level arguments to work and report the exact same values, in strata label and N, of my first output when renaming the headers?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip `tbl_strata()` altogether, and just use the `tbl_svysummary(by=)` argument. Does this not get you what you're after?

```r
tbl_svysummary_ex1 <-
  survey::svydesign(~1, data = as.data.frame(Titanic), weights = ~Freq) %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = Survived, percent = "row", include = c(Class, Age))
```

[image]

https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/dev/reference/tbl_svysummary.html#examples

Comment: Thanks, sadly this doesn't get what I need since later on I will need to do three way tables combining the `tbl_strata` with the `by` option in `tbl_svysummary`. Since `by` only allow 1 column to work with I need to do it with `tbl_strata`

Comment: You'll need to assign all the headers inside the tbl_strata() call. Only there will the dynamics {n} be available

Comment: Could you give me an example? Been triying what you said but keep getting error.

Comment: If you include reproducible examples in your posts, we can help with the details. Otherwise, I can give broad guidance